# Finding out actual changes/diff done in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible in Entity Framework to figure out the actual changes/diff which entity framework is going to make in the database?

Consider an example, let say that some rows are already present in the database and we try to add them again. Since the rows are already present, the actual changes/diff made in the database is null. Similarly, if I try to 10 rows, out of which only 3 got updated, then I want only those 3.

I was trying using `DbContext.ChangeTracker` to achieve the same but it looks like that it returns all the rows which we are trying to add/update/delete irrespective of whether some of them are already there in the database. Can someone confirm this behavior as well?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code in my base repository to get a dictionary of modified property names and the old DB values. The new values can be get easily by the TModel object itself.

```
private Dictionary<string, object> GetModifiedProperties(TModel model)
{
var entry = Context.Entry(model);

// entry is detached.
// set entry to database entry and its CurrentValues to model values
if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    object key = model.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(model);
    if (key == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The Entity you desire to update does not contain an Id value.");
    }

    var dbModel = Context.Set<TModel>().Find(key);
    var dbEntry = Context.Entry(dbModel);
    dbEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(model);

    entry = dbEntry;
    //entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}

var modifiedProps = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (var propertyName in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
{
    // copy only changed values to dict
    var prop = entry.Property(propertyName);
    if (prop.IsModified)
    {
        modifiedProps.Add(propertyName, prop.OriginalValue);
    }
}
return modifiedProps;
}
```

Sadly I found no elegant way to get the Key property. But "Id" worked for me. Only the changed properties should appear in the dictionary. Not exactly what you want but something to work with.

Edit: I use the Unit of Work pattern for my DAL. Every repository derives from my base repository, where this code comes from. The update method triggers the GetModifiedProperties() method.
You can than write an update method like that:

```
UnitOfWork.CutomerRepository.Update(Customer updated, out Dictionary<string, object> changedProps);
```